# Какой скрипт(программа) на сервере занимается фильтрацией согласно .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, сервер, firewall

На сервере в .htaccess прописано:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from a.b.c.d
```

А вот какой скрипт или программа задействует это правило и сравнивает ip c  a.b.c.d, чтобы совпадало? и как его настроить так, чтобы оно этот ip, если он не совпадает записывало в файл ignored.txt построчно? Сервер на apache+nginx

Comment: .htaccess это конфигурационный файл сервера Apache

Comment: @AlexeyTen я бы не называл этот файл "конфигурационным файлом сервера Apache". Конфигурационный файл это `httpd.conf` со всеми includ-ами. А `.htaccess` - это всего лишь **configuration changes on a per-directory basis**. 1) этот файл можно отключить - `AllowOverride None` 2) этот файл можно "переименовать" - `AccessFileName ".config"` и тогда .htaccess вообще выпадает из контекста веб-сервера.

Answer (score 0):

> какой скрипт или программа задействует это правило и сравнивает ip c a.b.c.d

Это делает модуль Апача [mod_access_compat](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_access_compat.html#deny)

> как его настроить так, чтобы оно этот ip, если он не совпадает записывало в файл ignored.txt построчно

Никак. Этот модуль не умеет таких действий.

То, что вам надо, возможно получится с помощью `Conditional logging`:

```
CustomLog logs/ignored.log common "expr=%{REMOTE_ADDR} -in {'a.b.c.d','f.e.g.h'}"
```

Либо что-то другое, похожее на это.

Comment: А если сервер будет не apache, а только nginx?

Comment: @ArturHan не знаю. Если будет только nginx, то вы задавайте новый вопрос про nginx.